# Can I update my review of an app without an iPhone?

Tags: ios-appstore

Is it possible to edit a review I have left from the web, without using an iPad or iPhone? I left a poorly rated review for an app that had an issue, but the developer has since fixed the issue. However, I have now switched from using an iPad to using an Android tablet. Is there any way to update or delete my old review?